# Can we get events for multiple calendar id's using Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

Right now Google Calendar API has `list` API which takes `calendarId` and provides us with events of that calendar.

I have a scenario where I need to get events for multiple calendar Id's.

Instead of looping over multiple Id's and requesting calendar events `n` number of times, can I just pass multiple Id's in one request and get their events ?

Not sure if they have API support for this scenario.

Comment: Jaspreet have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

No the API does not support this, each API request is paired with its unique keys that grant them access to one account, each token has the ability to only request connection from one account, so the only option is to iterate through each ID individually, this would be true for almost all API's of webservers.

The same goes for Calendar ID, in the API call, Calendar ID can only be a string and in the backend that string is matched with users Calendar Id, so any attempt to add multiple Id's will result in breaking the entire query.

`events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()`

In this CalendarID has to be a string that is matched with the database.

The biggest reason for this would be that this is a very unique problem-solution and they might not have an incentive to support this feature as this does not make sense form a business perspective.

Comment: I am using unique token/clientId of one particular account only and it doesn't change for multiple calendar Id's. Using one token only, I am getting events for multiple 'SHARED' calendars. Sorry I missed it in above question.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh Still the answer remains same, you will have to loop over all the Calendar ID's, there is only one function call, and it only accepts one Calendar ID as a string. I will edit the answer accordingly.