# Get event times from all calendars in googleCal api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

What I am trying to do:

Get start times of all events in all calendars from a work calendar(its fine if its only the calendars the business is "owner" on). Right now I have been connected to 'primary' but I need it to include everything.

```js
calendar.events
    .list({
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: CAL_ID,
      timeMin: date,
      showDeleted: false,
      singleEvents: true,
      maxResults: 20,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
    })
    .then((data) =>
      res.status(200).send(data),
    )
```

After looking at the docs, it doesn't look like there's a way to put multiple calendar Ids into calendar.events.list. I cant just calendarId: [calId1,calId2].

So does this mean I have to make multiple calls to each calendar to find the times of all events?

Additional info:
I am using a service account, just switched from Oauth so maybe there is something else I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking that there was a similar question as yours in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340327/can-we-get-events-for-multiple-calendar-ids-using-google-calendar-api). I as well checked the documentation for the [calendars.events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) and it seems that the API call can only handle one calendarID per call, a solution would be that you make a [calendarList.List](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list) to retrieve the calendarID of the account you are looking for and then loop with each Id using calendars.events.list.

Edit: I was able to run this code that gets the calendarID for all the calendars that my account has and list the first 5 events:

```js
function listCalendarEvents() {
  var calendars;
  var pageToken;
  do {
    calendars = Calendar.CalendarList.list({
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken  
    });
      if (calendars.items && calendars.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < calendars.items.length; i++) {
      var calendar = calendars.items[i];
      Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', calendar.summary, calendar.id); // retrieves the calendar information along with the calendar ID
      var calendarId = calendar.id; // assigning the calendar ID from the loop.
      var now = new Date();
      var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
      timeMin: now.toISOString(),
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
      maxResults: 5
  });
        if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) { //loop to retrieve the 5 events
        for (var j = 0; j < events.items.length; j++) {
        var event = events.items[j];
        if (event.start.date) {
        // All-day event.
        var start = new Date(event.start.date);
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleDateString());
      } else {
        var start = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleString());
            }
          }
        } else {
        Logger.log('No events found.');
        }
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No calendars found.');
    }
    pageToken = calendars.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Comment: "loop with each id"; So loop the entire call with changing Id for each iteration?

Comment: Yes, I was able to build a small sample on how you will do it.